# Why might SketchFab keep rejecting me as a seller?

Tags: assets, 3d-modeling

I've tried three times to get accepted as a seller on SketchFab but have been rejected on each occasion; with no clear explanation as to why.

After asking for more details, I eventually received a response indicating they were looking for "unique content", or the content wasn't suitably unique/original.

Does anybody have experience in applying for SketchFab seller status, and what they might mean by "unique content". Surely coming up with something completely unique, would be almost impossible?

My SketchFab user is: https://sketchfab.com/Gorillapoo965

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about how to develop a game or game mod. You may want to ask this question on a SketchFab user group instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about game development.